# Android: Uploading Strings To Server

Tags: java, android, web, webserver, httpclient

I'm trying to let my users be able to report small errors my android application automatically catches to my server. It's nothing big, just a small text box and send button.

It's supposed to send 3 strings (error, optional user description, and time) to a file on my website made specifically to capture those errors. The thing is, I have absolutely no idea how to do so. I only know how to let my application read info from my website but not the other way around.

Do I have to have a special script on my website? Are JSON Strings necessary? I need the string to be saved there. (Not temporarily)
I'm a bit of a newbie so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**-** There has to be a `script` running on your server, eg: `php script`.

**-** Its actually a **web-service** published on the server so that a client can access it.

**-** Then you will need to do a `HTTP Post` to the Server, its better to use `NameValuePair` along with it to send the data.

**This is my code for doing HTTP POST:**

```
public String postData(String url, String xmlQuery) {

        final String urlStr = url;
        final String xmlStr = xmlQuery;
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                HttpClient httpclient = MySSLSocketFactory.getNewHttpClient();

                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlStr);

                try {

                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                            1);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("xml", xmlStr));

                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                    Log.d("Vivek", response.toString());

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    InputStream i = entity.getContent();

                    Log.d("Vivek", i.toString());
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(i);

                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

                    String s = null;

                    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {

                        Log.d("YumZing", s);
                        sb.append(s);
                    }

                    Log.d("Check Now", sb + "");

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } /*
                 * catch (ParserConfigurationException e) { // TODO
                 * Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace(); } catch
                 * (SAXException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 * e.printStackTrace(); }
                 */
            }

        });

        t1.start();
        try {
            t1.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Getting from Post Data Method " + sb.toString());

        return sb.toString();
    }
```

**//////////////////////////// Edited Part ///////////////////////////////////**

**Server side php code:**

```
<?php

require_once(ROOT.'/lab/lib/xyz_api_int.php');

try {

    //setup the sdk
    $api = YumzingApiInt::_get(
        Config::get('api_int','url'),
        Config::get('api_int','key'),
        Config::get('api_int','secret')
    );

    //connect to the api
    $api->connect();

    //check our token
    echo $api->getToken();

} catch(Exception $e){
    sysError($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very useful! Would you mind showing me the script running on the server?

Comment: @Pkmmte i have added the server side script as required by you... pls see the edited part

Answer (score 0):

You just need to post values by http to a php script on your server that will save those values in your file or a database.

Comment: And how exactly do I do that?

Comment: By learning some basic php and understanding how it works to send data to a script. You could send it by calling an url that would look like "http://yourserver.org/saveerrrors.php?error=blabla&time=01011970 (that would be a get request but a post would be a better fit for the job).